# Spring boot security - Cannot autowire service in web security config with custom Authentication Provider

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, autowired

First of all I have two projects: **core** where I have DTOs, Services and DAOs, and **admin** that is just for Web Services. Web services works perfect against data base, but now I'm trying to use Spring Security with a custom Authentication Provider against data base, but when deployed got

```
Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authenticationProvider'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'ctsAuthenticationProvider': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'usuarioServicio'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'usuarioServicio': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'usuarioGestor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'usuarioGestor': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'usuarioDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'usuarioDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [ec/com/app/core/CoreApplication.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sessionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.jpa.HibernateEntityManagerFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

This is my code. WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "ec.com.app.core", "ec.com.app.admin" })
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CtsAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").access("permitAll").anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").and()
            .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").deleteCookies("remove")
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class).exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new UnauthorizedEntryPoint()).and().csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        AuthenticationFilter authFilter = new AuthenticationFilter();
        try {
            authFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
        authFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new CtsRequestMatcher());
        authFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
        authFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(new RestAuthenticationFailureHandler());
        return authFilter;
    }
}
```

My custom authentication provider CtsAuthenticationProvider

```
@Component
public class CtsAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private IUsuarioServicio usuarioServicio;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        // some authentication code
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return ProviderAuthenticationToken.class.equals(authentication);
    }
}
```

My AuthenticationFilter

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        // some validation code
    }
}
```

And my Service UsuarioServicio

```
@Service
public class UsuarioServicio implements IUsuarioServicio{
    // Some services
}
```

I have been using this service without any problem in some web services but now I'm trying to implement security and get this error

Comment: It looks like the problem is related to ec.com.app.core.CoreApplication class where you trying to autowire HibernateSessionFactory.

Comment: Did you start database server before starting your application?

Comment: Yes, is like ec.com.app.core.CoreApplication is not in the same context as security config (it is on another project), and yes, database server is running and working